# In QListWidget how do i check if QListWidgetItem already exists based on its Data member

Tags: c++, qt

im setting item's in QListWidget and in each QListWidgetItem im setting id like this:

```
newItem->setData(Qt::DisplayRole,ID);
```

now each time before im adding the itemi wish to check if already there is item with the same data in the list . 
how can i do that ... i don't think the findItems will help me here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me assume that type of `ID` is `int` (cause you didn't specify it).

```
bool found = false;
for (int i = 0; i < list->count(); ++i) {
    if (list->item(i)->data(Qt::DisplayRole).toInt() == ID_to_match) {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (!found) {
    do_something_here();
}
```

Comment: There is no other way I can think of. It is a sort of search: search by `data` field. You can't complete search faster than `O(n)` in general case (not considering questions about binary search, etc) what requires a loop. If you are not operating billions of items this should be fast enough. Especially if type of `ID` is simple enough to compare, like `int`. You can create seperate function called like `search_by_data` if you want and place the code above here.